# Use a drop-down form option as a query string

Tags: php, regex

I have some data that is being displayed when I input a query string that matches a folder name.

```
<div class="content">
    <form>
        <select name="s1">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
            <?php
            $domain_date = trim($_GET['domain']);
            foreach(glob(__DIR__ . '/sources/domains/*') as $filename){
                $filename = basename($filename);
                echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

`$domain_date = trim($_GET['domain']);` - This grabs the `.php?domain=2019-04-22` query string that is matched to a folder name called '2019-04-22'.

The above forEach spits out all the folders in that directory which is what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAk7A.png

Next, I have a if statement that checks if a domain query string exists and then continues:

```
try {

    if (!isset($_GET['domain']) || empty($_GET['domain'])) {
        echo "Please supply a domain- Ex: ?domain=2019-04-23";
        exit;
    } else {
        $domain_dir = __DIR__ . "/sources/domains/$domain_date/domains.csv";
    }
```

Now I'm stuck on how I can make the query string change when an option is selected on the form drop-down and have it continue to the try { statement.